# How to improve performance of a query that joins three tables?

Tags: mysql, performance, php

I want to fetch data from three tables: table A, table B and table C.

1. Table A in databaseA has the `customerid` column which is a primary key
2. Tables B and C in databaseB also have same column `customerid` (not primary key).

I want to retrieve the last transaction date in table A and table B for each customer in table A.

Expected result should have these columns:

1. customerID
2. Max(date in table B)
3. Max(date in table C)

The query below takes forever to run. How do I optimize the query to get desired result in less than 5 sec?

NB: tableA and tableB have about 10 million data each and both databases have the same character set.

```
select
   a.customerid, 
   a.custname as name,   
   max(b.lastdate) as lastdt,
   max(c.lastdate) as lastdtc,

     case 
        when  max(b.lastdate) < date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day) 
          and max(c.lastdate) > date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day)
                  then 'INACTIVE'
        when  max(c.lastdate) < date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day) 
         and  max(b.lastdate) < date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day) 
                  then 'DORMANT'
        when  max(c.lastdate) is null 
         and  max(b.lastdate) < date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day)
                  then 'DORMANT'
        else 
                       'ACTIVE'
        end as Status
  from 
           database1.table a
     inner join 
           database2.table b
           on a.customerid=b.customerid
        left join 
          database2.table c
           on a.customerid=c.customerid
           where a.customername like concat('$fromclient','%')
    group by a.customerid
         order by lastdt
    limit $fromclient offset $fromclient
```

Comment: please add tables definition (with current indexes)

Comment: Can you provide an execution plan? Offhand the `where a.customername like concat('$fromclient','%')` looks potentially problematic. A like on a string in a largerish table isn't typically the most performant thing.

Comment: left like is not a issue, but need understand - it indexed or not? other what help to understand performance problems - SHOW INDEX FROM tableA (same for table B) - in additional to table schema it show potential indexes cardinality and allow +- understand number of records filtered by WHERE conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Build a query that computes lastdt, lastdtc, and status.

Step 2:  Use that as a "derived" table to join to the other table(s) for the rest of the info.

The intent of Step 1 is to focus on the complexity of the `GROUP BY` and yield a much smaller table.  Then Step 2 has less work to do.